# How important is Graphics Ram for hashing

Tags: mining-hardware, altcoin, memory

Some altcoins are designed to be "memory intensive" to avoid use of ASICs to mine them.

Does the RAM refered to here, mean the RAM of the computer or the RAM on the GFX card itself.

When looking at passmark these two GFX cards get almost the same score 8687 vs 8773:
[GTX 1060 (3GB) vs GTX 1060 (6GB) comparison on passmark](https://www.videocardbenchmark.net/compare.php?cmp%5B%5D=3566&cmp%5B%5D=3548)

For gaming the ram can be important for having high-resolution textures in ram. But how much does it matter for hashing memory intensive hashes?